# Creating and using an interface for a history-object in React Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that takes in a history object as props. For now it is just typed as any, but I would like to type it to the appropriate object. How do i set up and use an interface for this?

Object:
[image: Object representation]

My code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import Search from 'antd/lib/input/Search';

const MyPatients = (props: any) => {
    console.log(props);
    const handleSearch = (value: any) => {
        console.log(value);
        setPatientID(value);
    };

    const [patientID, setPatientID] = useState();
    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ marginTop: 90 }}></div>
            <Row gutter={[60, 40]} justify={'center'}>
                <Col span={300}>
                    <p>Søk med personnummer for å finne en pasient.</p>
                    <Search
                        style={{ width: 400 }}
                        placeholder="Søk etter en pasient!"
                        onSearch={handleSearch}
                    />
                </Col>
            </Row>
            {patientID &&
                props.history.push({ pathname: 'Pasient', state: patientID })}
        </>
    );
};
export default MyPatients;
```

Comment: You should be able to get it from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/history . Please check on your side if it is the correct representation.

Comment: I think this is the right package for me. Would you mind showing me how to implement it in my example? I am very new to Typescript, it confuses me a bit.

Comment: Added an answer. Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it does ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [this history](https://github.com/mjackson/history), you can install corresponding [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/history) by running `npm install --save @types/history`in your project.

Once that is done, you can use the `History` type as such:

```
...
import { History } from 'history';

interface Props {
    history: History;
}

const MyPatients = (props: Props) => {...}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking, although the implementation in my case was slightly different.
I met another problem, however: When using it like this, and binding the value of handleSearch to IHandleValue { value: number;}, i get the error :



Type '(value: IHandleValue) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: string, event?: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent> | KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> | undefined) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IHandleValue'.  TS2322

Comment: I don't know anything about `IHandleValue` or the API of this `Search` component. In order to keep this question clean, i'd suggest asking another question if needed.